# Chrome App Authentication fails with chrome.runtime.identity.getAuthToken: Authorization page could not be loaded

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I authenticate my user when they hit the `sign in` button in my Chrome app. This opens up a new page in Chrome, prompting them to sign in with their Google account. Then, a popup opens asking for the permissions that my app requests. When they click ok, the app receives `token` -- it all worked fine until I switched to a different locale.

When I test the app in Korean locale, `token` is **undefined** after a successful sign in. I investigated further and I found out that I get the error `chrome.runtime.identity.getAuthToken: Authorization page could not be loaded`.

```
extensions::lastError:133 Unchecked runtime.lastError while running identity.getAuthToken: Authorization page could not be loaded.
    at chrome-extension://APP_ID/foreground/bundle/app.js:29630:24
    at chrome-extension://APP_ID/foreground/bundle/app.js:28068:46
    at Object.loadUserPlaylists (chrome-extension://APP_ID/foreground/bundle/app.js:27679:13)
    at SidebarPlaylists.onSignInAndLoadUserPlaylists (chrome-extension://APP_ID/foreground/bundle/app.js:42014:19)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallback (chrome-extension://APP_ID/foreground/bundle/app.js:11872:13)
    at executeDispatch (chrome-extension://APP_ID/foreground/bundle/app.js:11717:22)
    at Object.executeDispatchesInOrder (chrome-extension://APP_ID/foreground/bundle/app.js:11737:8)
```

This prevents anyone who's in Korea from signing in and using my Chrome app. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

**Update:**

Adding the following permissions didn't work:

```
"https://*.chromiumapp.org/*", "https://chromiumapp.org/",
"https://*.apps.googleusercontent.com/", "https://apps.googleusercontent.com/",
"https://apps.googleusercontent.com/", "https://apps.googleusercontent.com/",
"https://*.chromiumapp.org/*/*"
```

**Update2:**

I tried using `launchWebAuthFlow()` instead of `identity.getAuthToken()` as well.

```
  chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow({
    url: "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?scope=email&response_type=token&client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri="+chrome.identity.getRedirectURL()+"&prompt=consent",
    interactive: true
  }, function(respUrl) {
    //respUrl is empty
    debugger;
    //getUserPlaylists(token, dispatch);
```

This also gives me

`extensions::lastError:133 Unchecked runtime.lastError while running identity.launchWebAuthFlow: Authorization page could not be loaded.`

Error.

Comment: Does cleaning data/cache help with the locale issue? I can't find anything relating locale and `getAuthToken`, the nearest reference there is is for installing the extension via [External Extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions)

Comment: How do I clean up data/cache before the auth logic?

Comment: Yea it's quite weird that this problem only happens when I switch locales. It'd be great if I can see what causes `Authorization..` error.

Comment: Any other news here?